# Get isLoading state of manually initiated RTK Query mutation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rtk-query

I'm working on a Nextjs project with RTK Query. Can someone tell me how to access the isLoading state of the mutation that is initiated like this https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#initiate. I don't want to use the generated hook `useLoginMutation` but instead get the data by unwrapping the returned result after dispatching like this `await dispatch(api.endpoints.login.initiate()).unwrap()` because I don't want my form to re render. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> because I don't want my form to re render.

Hi, RTK Query author here.

Generally, you can use the `selectFromResult` option to reduce the amount of fields returned from the hook, and as such also reduce the amount of rerenders (as less things are changing).

Generally though, I have to strongly advise you: don't care about the amount of rerenders on this level. React is **made** to fastly rerender your components. One, two, or even five rerenders within a 1-3 seconds frame should not make **any** difference for your application - usually, your component will rerender on every keypress in your form anyways!

*If, and only if* you are seeing actual performance degradation, you get to the point of optimizing things like this - and then you would see if somewhere you have dozens or hundreds of rerenders, but still do not care about single-digit rerender numbers. If single-digit rerenders are a problem for you, you have heavy computation logic inside your components, and you need to optimize *that* - the execution of one of your component functions should always be in the sub-milliseconds. Then that's the place to optimize.

As for triggering the mutation with `initiate`: It will be `loading` until your `await` continues and done after that. If you just need that information, there is no need to access an `isLoading` state. You must set the component state if you need that information in your component. And that would trigger a rerender. You see where I am going: use the hooks! That's what they are made for.

Also, if using `initiate`: make sure to `unsubscribe` the result afterward or it will stay in cache forever. Again, this is something the hooks do for you.